# Invalid expression term 'string'

Tags: c#, constructor

error:

> Invalid expression term 'string'

Constructor:

```
public Car(string make, string model, int condition, double price, int passenger)
  :base(string make, model, condition, price)
```

Answer (score 7):

**Problem :** while sending parameters to `base class` constructor you don't need to use `datatype`.
**Solution :** Remove `string` from `base()` parameter `make`

Try This:

```
public Car(string make, string model, int condition, double price, int passenger )
           :base(make, model, condition, price)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public Car(string make, string model, int condition, double price, int passenger )
       :base(make, model, condition, price)
```

simply remove the "string" - you are calling a constructor like a normal function, so you dont need the keyword string